# Segmentation fault for minesweeper program c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, minesweeper

I think the problem is in my constructor. It starts to run and "place bombs" into the 2d array (grid), but it stops in the middle. (sometimes it'll run the whole way through...

```
SweeperGrid::SweeperGrid(const int initialRows, const int initialCols, const int density){
if ((initialRows<5 || initialCols<5) || (density<25 || density>75)) {
    throw out_of_range("Grid not large enough (number of rows or columns cannot be fewer than 5) or density is too low or high (must be between 25% and 75%)");
}

numRows = initialRows;
numColumns = initialCols;
numBombs = 0;

grid = new SweeperCell*[numRows];
for(int i=0; i <numRows; i++){
    grid[i] = new SweeperCell[numColumns];
}

srand(time(0));
for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<numColumns; j++){
        if(rand()%100+1<=density){
            PlaceBomb(i, j);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the PlaceBomb function:

```
void SweeperGrid::PlaceBomb(int row, int col){
cout<<row<<", "<<col<<endl;

if ((row<0||row>=numRows)||(col<0||col>=numColumns)){
    throw out_of_range("Out of bounds (PlaceBomb)");
}

At(row, col).PlaceBomb();
numBombs++;

//add if statements so it doesn't go out of bounds
if (row==0) {
    At(row+1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row+1, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row+1, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
}

if (row==0&&col==0) {
    At(row+1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row+1, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
}

if (col==0) {
    At(row-1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row+1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row+1, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row-1, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
}

if (row==numRows-1) {
    At(row-1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row-1, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row-1, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
}

if (row==numRows-1&&col==numColumns-1) {
    At(row-1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row-1, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
}

if (col==numColumns-1) {
    At(row-1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row+1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row-1, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row+1, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
}

if (row==0&&col==numColumns-1) {
    At(row+1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row+1, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
}

if (row==numRows-1&&col==0) {
    At(row-1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row-1, col+1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
}
```

**IncrementNumAdjacent is in another file and I'm sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `IncrementNumAdjacent` calls and some of them can be out of range.

For example:

```
if (row==0) {
    At(row+1, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
    At(row, col-1).IncrementNumAdjacent();
```

what happens if `col` is 0 at this point?

It is probably easier to have a `safeIncrementNumAdjacent(int row, int col)` method in your `SweeperGrid` class that just ignores out of range items. Something like:

```
void SweeperGrid::safeIncrementNumAdjacent(int row, int col) {
   if (row >= 0 && row < numRows && col >= 0 & col < numCols)
      At(row, col).IncrementNumAdjacent();
}
```

then just call that for the 8 locations around the current point.

Comment: Thank you! I'll test it out!

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't working... There's no segmentation error, but it occasionally increments too much? Also numBombs returns a few more "bombs" than there actually are.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is a bit hard to say, but possibly your random bomb placer is placing two bombs in the same location. That would cause what you describe.

Comment: Oops, No it isn't that, sorry - your for loop won't place bombs in the same location. Maybe ask another question with the new code.